# iTunes - adding content to third party app

Tags: ios, itunes, data-transfer

Prior to this iTunes 12 update, there was a way to navigate to the apps on your iPad and select a third party app from the App Store, then be able to 'add media' to that application. I would put home videos and other content to CineXPlayer this way.

With iTunes 12, I no longer see this option for my third party video player. Is this no longer supported? Are third party video apps out of business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Launch iTunes
- Plug in iDevice, then...

  1. select iDevice
  2. Select Apps
  3. Scroll down on the right-most scroll-bar until you see the **File Sharing** header
  4. In that section, select your app
- Then you can drag & drop to the right section

*I shrunk my iTunes window down as small as it would go to show all the info without taking up too much room in here*

[image]

Rebooting the phone may help if connectivity is an issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think that's the problem. My iDevice is no longer showing up in that bar you highlighted (#1)

Comment: then that's a different issue entirely. Is it plugged in? Does the cable work? Is your USB hub functioning correctly?

Comment: Debugging right now. It's definitely receiving a charge. So functioning cable isn't the problem.

Comment: charge & data are not necessarily carried on the same core. At minimum, unplug, reboot phone & try again - or try another cable

Comment: rebooted and now the devices show up. And following your instructions, everything works as depicted. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I'll port some of that info into the answer for future users - comments are ephemeral, answers stay.

Comment: and that is a + from me for shrinking action :) = very considerate of you.

Comment: Does this still work? I cant seem to see this on latest iTunes 12.3.1 with iOS Nine

Comment: Tell me of a Free sample app that it is working for you and I will try it out to test it

Comment: There's one right there in the picture