# Transferring file from Windows to iPhone through iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, usb, windows

A friend has a Windows 8 laptop and needs to copy a text file from the laptop over USB to her iPhone running iOS 7.

On the Windows side, I upgraded iTunes to the latest and greatest. When plugging the phone into the laptop, a window pops up prompting the user to sync their picture files, to which we agreed.
So it looks like everything works hardware- and software-wise. Incidently, the two Apple-related items in Device Manager are displayed correctly (ie. no exclamation point).

However, even after following [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12318?viewlocale=en_US&locale=fr_FR), I can't figure out how to copy a text file from Windows to the iPhone: The apps installed on the iPhone aren't listed in iTunes.

Is there an Apple-newbie article that explains how to do this?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Should I forget about iTunes and go for [iExplorer](http://lifehacker.com/5869822/how-to-sync-documents-and-other-files-to-ios-without-itunes) instead?

---

Edit : problem solved. Turns out the USB cable and/or the USB port used was a bit flaky, which explains why the iPhone would or wouldn't be accessible in Windows. This, combined with this first use of iTunes which caused us from not knowing how to proceed to transfer/copy a file from Windows to the iPhone. Thanks Tetsujin.

Comment: You can't transfer it just "to the phone", you need to drop it to an app that can handle it - see my answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167814/85275

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is about the Apple version of iTunes. The Windows version doesn't look the same.

Comment: use google drive or icloud

Comment: iTunes is iTunes, makes no difference which platform, the cosmetic differences are small, the functionality is identical. That picture was probably v11, but 12 is almost the same.

Comment: Elsewhere, I'm told the Windows version of iTunes is incapable of transferring non-multimedia files to an iPhone because Windows doesn't see it as a USB keydrive (ie. external hard drive). Can someone confirm before I spend more time on this?

Comment: OS X does not see the iPhone as an USB key drive either —not by default anyway.